# radio button is not behave properly when click on them

Tags: html, reactjs

When I click on 1 div radio button it works as normal. But as I click on add more button and then click on second div radio button my first div radio button unchecked automatically.

Why is this happens?

Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';

class Body extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            length :1,
        }
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    }

    add(event) {
        this.setState({length: this.state.length+1});
    }

    render() {
    
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    Array(this.state.length).fill().map((e,i)=>{
                        return <div>
                            <input type="text" name="name" 
placeholder="Enter name"/><br/>
                            Male:<input type="radio" name="gender" 
value="Male"/>
                            Female:<input type="radio" name="gender" 
value="Female"/>
                        </div>
                    })
                }
                <button onClick={this.add}>Add More</button>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Body;
```

[image: Here in image when I click on second row radio button it automatically unchecked the first row radio button which I previously checked]

Comment: a `radio group` allows only one item to be checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name={`${i}name`} placeholder="Enter name" />
  <br />
  Male:<input type="radio" name={`${i}gender`} value="Male" />
  Female:<input type="radio" name={`${i}gender`} value="Female" />
</div>
```

So your names are the same, and that creates the issue.